# Advanced Custom Fields - Cannot update User Field properly

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

i´ve a User Field (Multiple Selectable) that i´ve to update with a Webservice.

It´s working with something like

```
add_post_meta($post_id,'followers',$followers);
```

being $followers an Array of User IDs.

This is apparently working (I see the correct data on the WP admin) but i have seen data is not being storing properly on wp_postmeta table. When i use mi webservice, user IDs store without quotes on that table, something like

```
a:1:{i:0;i:1348;}
```

But if i´ve make any modification in the admin i get:

```
 a:1:{i:0;i:"1348";}
```

When i try to make a reverse query in WP, y use something like

```
                        'meta_query' => array(
                        'relation' => 'OR',
                        array(
                            'key' => 'followers',
                            'value' => '"' . $current_user->ID . '"',
                            'compare' => 'LIKE'
                        ),
```

so I need user ids always being stored with quotes in my webservice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The right way is to store with double quote. In your query you have to serialize your search and convert to string like this :

```
 'meta_query' => array(
                   'relation' => 'OR',
                          array(
                                'key' => 'followers',
                                'value' => serialize(strval($current_user->ID)),
                                'compare' => 'LIKE'
                            ),
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that i can´t store data properly using WP or ACF functions. If i use update_post_meta or ACFs update_field functions, data is stored without quotes. Example: [code]add_post_meta($post_id,'administradores',$administradores);[/code] being $administradores an array of user IDs, produces a DB insertion without quotes.